# How to passing Parameters

Tags: c#

I am having issues with passing decimal variable into a function. What I am trying to do: at the top of the code I declared the variable `Money` as decimal `private decimal Money` and I then set the value to `0`. I want to use that variable in the `AddMoney` function but when I declared the function `static void AddMoney` I don't know what arguments to put in the `()` to use the variable I declared outside of the function.

```
namespace program
{
    class data
    {
        private decimal Money = 0;

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Menu();
        }
        static void Menu()
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
            switch (cki.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad1:
                    case ConsoleKey.D1:
                        Home();
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad2:
                    case ConsoleKey.D2:
                        AddMoney();
                        break;
        static void Home()
        {
            Menu();
        }

        static void AddMoney()
        {
            Clear();
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
            string imputMoney;
            decimal tempMoney;
            PrintToScreen(1, 1, "" + Money);
            PrintToScreen(1, 2, "Please select an option from bellow: ");
            PrintToScreen(1, 3, "1. Update the current amount (add money to existing amount)");
            PrintToScreen(1, 4, "2. Update a new total (rase and change the total)");

            cki = Console.ReadKey();

            switch (cki.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.NumPad1:
                case ConsoleKey.D1:
                    Clear();
                    PrintToScreen(1, 1, "Please enter a amount: ");
                    imputMoney = Console.ReadLine();
                    tempMoney = System.Convert.ToDecimal(imputMoney); 
                    tempMoney + Money = Money;
                    PrintToScreen(1, 1, "" + Money);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Menu();
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.NumPad2:
                case ConsoleKey.D2:
                    Clear();
                    PrintToScreen(1, 1, "Please enter a amount: ");
                    imputMoney = Console.ReadLine();
                    tempMoney = System.Convert.ToDecimal(imputMoney);
                    Money = 0;
                    tempMoney = Money;
                    PrintToScreen(1, 1, "" + Money);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Menu();
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a private member of another class. Instead, you might want to make it public. Then `AddMoney` should take a `data` variable. So it should look like this : `AddMoney(data dataVariable)`. Now that you made the `data.Money` public, you can use it as you like.
P.S in C# we use PascalCase for class names.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` class holds a decimal named `Money`, but it's private so it cannot be accessed outside that class.

Typically if you want `Money` to be changed by an external method, you'd make it publically accessible:

```
class data
{
    public decimal Money { get; set; }
}
```

Your method could then accept a `data` instance:

```
static void AddMoney(data myData)
{
    myData.Money += 10;
}

...

data someData = new data { Money = 12.01m };
AddMoney(someData);
// someData.Money will be 22.01 now.
```

It's not easy answering questions like these; we have no clue what you want to do with the `data` class, and there are quite a few ways to pass parameters to a method.